# How to configure HAProxy on Amazon Linux AMI with SSL/TLS Passthrough

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, haproxy, amazon-ami, amazon-elastic-ip

I'm trying to configure an Amazon Linux AMI instance that has an Elastic IP to act as Proxy to a standalone backend server. I'm trying to do HTTPS TCP Passthrough only but I can't get it to work! ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED!

```
 defaults
 mode     tcp
 log      global
 maxconn  15000

frontend https_frontend
 bind *:443
 mode tcp
 option tcplog
 default_backend https_backend

backend https_backend
  mode tcp
  balance roundrobin
  option ssl-hello-chk
  server app1 x.x.x.x:443 check
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luis,

Just some quick ideas:

Are you sure it is actually up and running?

netstat -l | grep 443

and/or

ps -ef | grep haproxy

Configure a stats listener so you can see if the health checks are working or not...

Simplify the health check or even remove to get it working.

Comment: Malcolm you're correct! HAProxy wasn't running because I was working on the copy .cfg instead of the original .cfg. Once I replaced the original .cfg with the copy .cfg, everything started working! Thank you!

Comment: Amazing how easy it is to do things like that, glad you fixed it :-).